# React binding method in constructor - how to pass in Argument

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working in React and upon reading [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) I decided to switch my incorporate binding of the event handler in my constructor as they recommend. The problem is, when I do so I lose the ability to pass in my form variable to the onChange Material-UI Checkbox function. Here is my relevant code

**client/prospect/ProspectForm.jsx**

```
class ProspectForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // Bind Methods
    this.handleChangeProductType = this.handleChangeProductType.bind(this)

    this.state = {
    inquiryDate: moment().toDate(),
    productTypes: {list: [], other: '', },
    otherChecked: false,
    }
  }

  handleChangeProductType(a){
    console.log(a)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="field">
        { this.props.allProductTypes.map((referralSource, k) =>
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.checkProductType(referralSource)}
          onCheck={this.handleChangeProductType(referralSource)}
          label={referralSource}
          key={k} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {

    const productTypes = [
      "Independent Living",
      "Memory Care",
      "Beauty Shop",
      "Skilled Nursing",
      "Therapy Rental",
    ]

  return {
    productTypes: productTypes,
  }
}, ProspectForm)
```

So essentially, when I call the onChange with the argument like that

```
this.handleChangeProductType(referralSource)
```

it doesn't actually call the method. When I call it like this

```
onChange={this.handleChangeProductType}
```

it does call the method, but I have no access to the referralSource in the function, which I need to set the state object so I can track which ones are checked and send them along with my form. So how do I do this in a way where I can set use the bind method in the constructor, and pass along my argument to the method? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136
https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-part-2-d83a52a044ee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the `bind` in the constructor.  Instead, you can bind it in the `onCheck` declaration and pass in the referralSource parameter to `bind`.

```
onCheck={this.handleChangeProductType.bind(null, referralSource)}
```

Comment: That is how I originally had it, I just happen to read about the recommended way of doing it and thought i'd switch. Guess i'll just do that, thanks. Also, why pass null as the first argument out of curiousity? I was passing (this, referralSource) before

Comment: I guess I actually need to pass it like (this, referralSource) because in the method I need access to the this.state object so I can set it

Comment: Doesn't this approach cause a new function to be created every time the render method is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it this way:

```
onCheck={(referralSource) => this.handleChangeProductType(referralSource)}
```

Comment: I changed my code to that and it allowed the method to be called but when I console.log the value it never comes through

Comment: you need to bind `handleChangeProductType ` first, you can bind it in your constructor function `this.handleChangeProductType = this.handleChangeProductType.bind(this)`

Comment: @chenkehxx Are you sure that arrow functions in the render are affected by binding in the constructor?

Comment: @kojow7, no,  arrrow function just means the context of this is called function. for example: `{(referralSource) => this.handleChangeProductType(referralSource)}` this means `this` of  `this.handleChangeProductType` equit the `this` of `render` function. but `this.handleChangeProductType = this.handleChangeProductType.bind(this) // in constructor function`, it means the `this` in `handleChangeProductType` is the instace of this class.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a wrapper component for the `<Checkbox />` that creates the appropriately 'loaded' function for you.

```
const ProductTypeCheckbox = ({
  referralSource,
  checkProductType,
  handleChangeProductType,
}) => {
  const isChecked = () => checkProductType(referralSource);
  const handleCheck = () => handleChangeProductType(referralSource);

  return (
    <Checkbox
      checked = { isChecked() }
      onCheck = { () => handleCheck() }
      label = { referralSource }
    />
  );
};
```

Then simply replace `<Checkbox />` in your list above with

```
<ProductTypeCheckbox
  key = { k }
  referralSource = { referralSource }
  checkProductType = { checkProductType }
  handleChangeProductType = { handleChangeProductType }
/>
```

This will create a bit of overhead, creating a new function for each item in the loop, but it is a clean separation dumb and smart components, and allows you to easily read what is being set where.